# how linux grep -oP print the pattern only

Tags: regex, linux, grep, pcre

```
# cat a.file
123123abc file2
274efcc4d8a0e8f61397be46bd4bfa37  file1
321  file1

# file="file1"
# grep -m 1 -oP "\K([\w]+) +$file" a.file
274efcc4d8a0e8f61397be46bd4bfa37  file1
```

How can I get the output `274efcc4d8a0e8f61397be46bd4bfa37` with the parameter `file1` line, and only use `grep` command without `|` or other command like `awk`?

Is there `grep -P` have some other parameters for only print the match pattern `\K([\w]+)` such as the result is `274efcc4d8a0e8f61397be46bd4bfa37`? Or Is there any implementation to get the result with `grep` only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```sh
$ file='file1'
$ grep -m1 -oP '\w+(?= +'"$file"'$)' a.file
274efcc4d8a0e8f61397be46bd4bfa37
```

`(?=regexp)` is a positive lookahead construct which helps you define an assertion without it being part of the matched portion. See [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) for more information on lookarounds.

I've also placed `'\w+(?= +'` and `"$file"` and `'$)'` next to each other, so that only the shell variable is under double quotes. The `$` anchor is used here to avoid partial match, for example `file1` vs `file1a` or `file11`. If your filename can have regexp metacharacters (for ex: `.`), then you'll need to use `'\w+(?= +\Q'"$file"'\E$)'` to match the filename literally.

Not sure why you do not want to use `awk` here, it is well suited for this task. String comparison comes in handy to avoid having to deal with regexp escaping.

```sh
awk -v f="$file" '$2==f{print $1; exit}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You misuse `\K`, it discards the matched text captures until current moment, it has no use at the beginning of the pattern.  `+file1` is consuming pattern, it will be returned as a match part.

Use ***non-consuming*** pattern:

```sh
grep -m 1 -oP "\w+(?=\s+$file\b)" a.file
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/WCWRnC/2). `\b` will disallow matching `file10`.

**EXPLANATION**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    file1                    'file1'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```